# Instagram API, diplaying medias in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, async-await, instagram-api

i am curently stuck in trying to set up an API on a react application. I did test my access token manually and it worked

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=${accessToken}
```

but i am stuck when its about to import theses data into the statement of the app.

I check the architecture of the component adding manually url into the state and it worked out, so i get the probleme is probably in the function that i called diplayInsta() or in the util/insta.js method

```
const Insta = {
  getAccessToken() {
    //check if token exist
    if (accessToken) {
      return new Promise(resolve => resolve(accessToken));
    }
    //token ref
    return fetch(`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/? client_id=${client_id}&redirect_uri=${redirectURI}&response_type=token`, {
      method: 'POST'
    }).then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).then(jsonResponse => {
      accessToken = jsonResponse.access_token;
    });
  },
  async display() {
    if (!accessToken) {
      this.getAccessToken();
    }
    try {
      let response = await fetch(`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=${accessToken}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        let jsonResponse = await response.json();
        let medias = jsonResponse.medias.data.map(media => ({
          id: media.data.id,
          image: media.data.images.standard_resolution.url
        }));
        return medias;
      }
      throw new Error('Request failed!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my github link of the project where you will found the whole project. https://github.com/erwanriou/reactisbroken

I feel that its probably a very small mistake but i can't found where it is...I a good soul could help me to show me the good direction...

UPDATE - After the first answer i did actualise the code and i now resolve the access token part but still stuck in displaying it into the state of the App.js That is my major problem curently

here a screen of the working promise :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w9wh3h3m58r3n06/Promise.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Theres a space in the url at "`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/? client_id". Might not be the problem but still an error

Comment: Yes true its a bug when i imported it here but its not the case in my code and github fortunatly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found myself the solution. i put it here in case some of you are block in a similar problem :

```
let accessToken;

const Insta = {
  getAccessToken() {
    if (accessToken) {
      return new Promise(resolve => resolve(accessToken));
    }
    const accessTokenMatch = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
    if (accessTokenMatch) {
      accessToken = accessTokenMatch[1];
      return accessToken;
    } else {
      const Url = `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=${client_id}&redirect_uri=${redirectURI}&response_type=token`
      window.location = Url;
    }
  },
  async display() {
    if (!accessToken) {
      this.getAccessToken();
    }
    try {
      let response = await fetch(`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=${accessToken}`, {
        method: 'GET'
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log(response);
        let jsonResponse = await response.json();
        let medias = jsonResponse.data.map(media => ({
          id: media.id,
          image: media.images.standard_resolution.url
        }));
        return medias;
      }
      throw new Error('Request failed!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Now the part to import the fetch data into the state is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import Header from '../Header/Header.js';
import MediaList from '../MediaList/MediaList.js';
import Insta from '../../util/insta.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mediasResult: [],
      accountName: 'Erwan'
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    Insta.display().then(medias => this.setState({mediasResult: medias}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header accountName={this.state.accountName}/>
        <MediaList medias={this.state.mediasResult}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In fact the componentDidMount save my day. Its that let you import fetch data into the state.