# Is it impossible share to instagram using react?(Not React-native)

Tags: reactjs

I want to share to an image or article instagram using reactjs.
I searched for it. It only example using react-native.
how to share to instagram only reactjs?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to integrate the API instagram and use it ... :)

For example : [Instagram API, diplaying medias in react application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756519/instagram-api-diplaying-medias-in-react-application)
and
https://github.com/pixochi/instagram-content-publishing-react-app

Take a look to the github link

Answer (score 0):

import Share from 'react-native-share';

const options = { title: 'XYZ', message:"HELLO", social: Share.Social.INSTAGRAM};

const shareResponse = await Share.shareSingle(options);

Comment: Question specifically says non react-native